# How to select in each row the last element with certain class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In each row there are some cells containing class `.meow`.
How do I select the **last** `.meow` element in **each row**?
The code below just selects all .meows...

```js
$("tr").each(function(){
  $(".meow").css("border", "3px solid red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr> <td><div class="meow">Meow</div><td>
       <td>Woof</td>
       <td><div class="meow">Meow</div><td>
  </tr>
  <tr> <td> <div class="meow">Meow</div><td>
       <td><div class="meow">Meow</div></td>
       <td>Woof<td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: have you tried `$(".meow").last().css("border", "3px solid red");`

Comment: sure, and it just selects the last meow in a whole table.

Comment: DOH, sorry! That gets the last .meow PERIOD, not the last in each row ... see my answer below for the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this

```js
$("tr").each(function(){
  $(this).find(".meow:last").css("border", "3px solid red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr> <td><div class="meow">Meow</div><td>
       <td>Woof</td>
       <td><div class="meow">Meow</div><td>
  </tr>
  <tr> <td> <div class="meow">Meow</div><td>
       <td><div class="meow">Meow</div></td>
       <td>Woof<td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: You target all `tr`s, while it should be the current one

Answer (score 2):

You should just use `querySelector`:

```
document.querySelector( ".child:last-of-type" );
```

And you can use querySelector on elements too, so use it on each row.

https://jsfiddle.net/L5fdhs7d/

Comment: yeah but why use that when you got jquery?

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Because it's faster, fully supported and standard and works perfectly.

Comment: Yes but if his project is already using jquery heavily, for the sake of consistency he should continue doing so... :)

Comment: well +1 for being the only one with an original idea and not stealing someone elses answer from the comments..

Comment: hey I didn't steal anything... ._. great minds think alike

Answer (score 1):

Change

`$("tr").each(function(){
  $(".meow").css("border", "3px solid red");
});`

to

`$("tr").each(function(){
    $(this).find(".meow:last").css("border", "3px solid red");
});`

https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/

Comment: It just selects the last meow, in a whole table. Not in each row.

Comment: My bad I didn't see that - Updated answer now but I see Theo got there before me :p

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's `last()` function.
Also, you need to base your search off of the current `tr`, so use `$(this).find()`.

`$(this).find(".meow").last().css("border", "3px solid red");`